# BlackScreen after install Nvidia Drivers

Tags: display, greeter, drivers, nvidia

I installed this with additional drivers for a nvidia gt520m but when I restart, black screen appear, this is a fresh elementary os loki; yesterday I installed manually the driver via terminal, but the black screen appear too; what I need to do? I can do CTRL + ALT + F1 but lightdm have some problem, so that restarted every 5 seconds, so I need to stop this via terminal with 
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop; what is the problem? If I dont install the nvidia drivers, I can manage all in the graphical system, but when I reboot with the nvidia drivers, black screen!

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled all of the Nvidia Drivers through the terminal in recovery mode. Then I installed nvidia-331 (a more stable version), with 
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-331` and then rebooted into the UI. Currently the brightness doesn't work and the scaling is off, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

The rule #1 for installing Nvidia Drivers is to disable the `xorg-nouveau` graphics driver package. Because it makes your computer into a black screen.

See this [post](http://lenovolinux.blogspot.pe/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html?m=1) for installing apropiately the nvidia driver.